# How to input " (double quote mark) in vim?

Tags: vim

Maybe a naive question as I am pretty new to vim.
I am trying to copy some text from website (system clipboard) into my vim editor. I learned at lots of places that I need to use `"+p` in vim normal mode. But when I try to enter the " (double quote) mark by pressing `shift+"`, it has no response at all. Nothing show up in the commend line.
I am using a +clipboard vim, and it's in Ubuntu.

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Yep, with the default VIM configuration, nothing will show up until you complete the sequence `"+p`. Does that not work?

Comment: Eh, the default configuration is just pretty minimal. I would absolutely recommend `set showcmd`, which will put in-progress commands in the bottom-right.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux Vim, there's no feedback by default. You can enable that by placing

```
set showcmd
```

into your `~/.vimrc`. From `:help 'showcmd'`:

> 'showcmd' 'sc'        boolean (Vim default: on, off for Unix, Vi default: off, set in |defaults.vim|)
>
> Show (partial) command in the last line of the screen.

New Vim instances will then show the incomplete command (e.g. `"*`) in the bottom right corner.